# Java: calling Interfaces without assigning implementations

Tags: java, interface, implementation

Is it possible to use an interface in Java with the JVM deciding which implementation takes care of the calls on it?

I mean something like

```
public class MyClass{
    private MyModelInterface myModel;

    public void doSmoething(){
        myModel.calculate();
    }
}
```

or do I have to pass on the reference to the implementation of the interface(-variable) every time like this

```
public class MyClass{
    private MyModelInterface myModel;

    public MyClass(MyModel myModel){
        this.myModel=myModel;}

    public void doSmoething(){
        myModel.calculate();
    }
}
```

The eclipse compiler doesnt show me any errors in the former example, but the JVM gives me null-pointer-exceptions when I try to assign mouse listeners or observers to such interfaces between model view and controller. I am unsure if this is the source of those exceptions or multiple threading in my program.

Comment: The example you cited is *NOT* an "interface".  You must use the keyword "interface".  And you cannot give an implementation for any of the methods in that interface.  It sounds like you've just defined a variable and never initialized it (hence the "nullPointerException").

Comment: Yes, but you'll still need to assign a reference to an implementation of the interface. If you're getting a NullPointerException you've not passed a valid reference to the class constructor

Comment: @FoggyDay: the first line is supposed to be a field in the class MyClass

Comment: You're always going to have to create an object before you can use it. Or before you can pass it to a method that tries to use it.   For example, `MyModelInterface myModel = new SomeClassThatImplementsMyModelInterface()`.   The JVM can't just magically "do something".

Comment: Why did you delete your Observer/Observable question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation needs to be alwasy provided somehow.

But the decission about which implementation will be used could be postponed to runtime using "Direct Injection".

I suggest you to read and learn about Spring Core.

Comment: If this is possible, I guess it explains why Eclipse did not show me an error. Too bad I assumed the JVM takes care of everything and wrote a lot of my code in a wrong way.  I will read about what you've said. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

No, you always have to pass an instance of some class implementing the interface. The JVM can't magically decide what the `calculate()` method is supposed to do.